# What is the cheapest way to use data for an Australian (Telstra) iPhone in the US?

Tags: usa, cellphones, australia, data-plans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data-plan for the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/data-plan-for-the-usa)

I'll be travelling to the US soon from Australia, and I was wondering what is the cheapest way to have 3G data in the US using my iPhone which has a Telstra SIM card.

Should I buy a local pre-paid SIM, or are there other options available?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate.  The question related specifically to Australia and Telstra users travelling to the US and the best options.

Comment: There are options to buy sim cards before heading to the US, like from http://www.travelgear.com.au/p/TMOBILEUSA/T-Mobile+USA+prepaid+mobile+phone+SIM+card+with+USD$30+credit".  I would be interested if anybody has experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: Agree with @kelso, this is not a duplicate at all. The duplicate links to data plans in the USA. This question asks what the cheapest avenue for someone with an Australian phone and service would be if they want to get data when travelling in the USA.

Comment: It is almost always cheaper to get a sim card at your destination, than it is to rely on roaming. You haven't stated whether you have a pre-paid or plan, nor how long you expect to be there. Assuming a plan you will be paying AU$3 a MB unless you get a "travel pack" which works out to $10 a day (including unlimited calls and text). Telstra don't appear to have roaming only data plans meaning that for data-only your best bet is to buy a local sim card (a list of which appears in the currently marked "duplicate question").