# Phone during a holiday to usa

Tags: usa, cellphones

I am visiting USA on a holiday next week. We would like to use a prepaid sim in our own mobile phones - Motorola G and a Samsung s4 mini. What is a recommended provider that will provide unlimited usa calls, free data up to 500mb and some talktime on international mobile phones?

Comment: and [Are there data plans for travelers in the USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/are-there-data-plans-for-travelers-in-the-usa).

Comment: Can you add countries for the "international mobile phones"? AFAIK, no carriers offers that, except for countries where the recipient of the call pays for the difference to the landline call fee.